# Dynamically update map

Tags: dictionary, set, velocity

I have some code like this:

```
$set($map = {"a": [1,1], "b", [2,2] } )

#foreach( $key in $map.keySet() )
  #set($val = $map.get($key).toList())
  #set($junk = $val.add(9))
  #set($junk = $map.put($val)
#end
```

At the end, I want `$map` to contain

```
{"a": [1,1,9], "b", [2,2,9] }
```

but because the `put()` reuses the same varible, the arrays are passed by reference, and `$map` ends up as:

```
{"a": [2,2,9], "b", [2,2,9] }
```

**update**

I think it should be possible with something like this but I suspect I need to escape the `$` in the variable names.

```
#evaluate( "$map.get($key).asList().add(9)" )
```

**Update 2**

I ended up changing the way my data was structured so that I didn't have arrays inside maps/sets. I didn't find a way to update them inside the set.